# How to interpret coefficients from a GARCH model?

Tags: r, time-series, garch

Recently I have opened a question here to understand the output of a GARCH model.
My goal is to understand if the series I'm checking is heteroscedastic or not.

I'm using the `garch()` function from the [tseries](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tseries/index.html) package.

First I built a linear regression like this:

```
mod <- lm(a ~ b)
```

Then I need to check if the residuals of this linear regression present heteroscedasticity.

I did:

```
g <- garch(resid(mod), order(c(1,1)))
```

and then

```
summary(g)
```

I get the follow output:

```
> summary(g) 

Call: 
garch(x = lm(A ~ B)$resi, order = order(c(1, 1))) 

Model: 
GARCH(1,2) 

Residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q    Max 
-4.2058 -1.0262  0.1404  1.1069  3.6553 

Coefficient(s): 
    Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
a0 3.361e-04  9.352e-05    3.594 0.000326 *** 
a1 3.045e-01  4.486e-02    6.787 1.14e-11 *** 
a2 1.209e-06  8.855e-02    0.000 0.999989    
b1 4.938e-01  1.060e-01    4.660 3.17e-06 *** 
--- 
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Diagnostic Tests: 
    Jarque Bera Test 

data:  Residuals 
X-squared = 18.84, df = 2, p-value = 8.108e-05 


    Box-Ljung test 

data:  Squared.Residuals 
X-squared = 49.7251, df = 1, p-value = 1.769e-12
```

Thanks to the user who answered my question, I now understand that the `ao` is the intercept and the other `a1` and `b1` are the coefficients I need to check to understand if this time series is heteroscedastic or not.

The problem (doubt) is that now I also see `a2` in the regression table: What does it stand for?

Is it correct to say that if all coefficients have a $p$-value above 0.05 (...)

Comment: I've made some edits to your question which still looks unfinished at the moment (please, fill the `(...)`!).

Answer (score 3):

The output says that **a2** is really insignificant.

What you have is (essentially) a hypothesis test that assumes homoscedasticity and can be rejected so that you would infer there really is heteroscedasticity.  What you seem to want is a test that assumes heteroscedasticity that you can reject in order to infer homoscedasticity.  In principle you could have such a test, but in practice I don't think you can.

Thinking like a Bayesian will help some, but it still isn't going to make a nice dividing line between "has volatility clustering" and "close enough to homoscedastic".